# Why JS always return 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'?

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

Okey, I saw a solution to this problem, but it’s not clear to me why it doesn’t work for me?
I use socket.io

// This is rooms

```
var rooms = {
            "1": [],
            "2": [],
            "3": [],
            "4": [],
            "5": []
};
```

and this is listener

```
socket.on('joinRoom', function (data) {

}
```

Why

```
rooms[1].push(1); // work?
```

Why

```
rooms["1"].push(1); // work?
```

And why

```
rooms[data.room].push(1); // not work?
```

And why

```
rooms["" + data.room].push(1) not work?
```

And why

```
rooms[data.room] = [];
rooms[data.room] = 1; // work?
```

data.room return 1;

Comment: What is the value of `data`?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier 
C#
public void JoinRoom()
    {
        jsonObject.AddField("room", currentRoomIndex);
        socketIOComponent.Emit("joinRoom", jsonObject);
        jsonObject.Clear();
    }


I send index of room (from 0 to 5)

Comment: Inspect what is received as `data` in client side code since that is where you have problems. Also show us how you determine it's not working

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, I resolved it. And How?
`if(data.room == 0)`
`socket.room = 0`

this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the conditions are not that clear (particularly, no clue what `data` is), the only reason why the following might work:

```
rooms[data.room] = [];
rooms[data.room] = 1;
```

Meanwhile this doesn't:

```
rooms[data.room].push(1);
```

Is that `data.room` returns something that is not a key of `rooms` yet.

Try to do this `rooms[data.room] = 1;` and then `console.log(rooms);` chances are that you will find 6 keys instead of 5.

By the way, when you set key/access its value, there's no need to convert your key into string. It's converted automatically. It even converts objects (to string `[object Object]`).